# How can I add new sections to an existing card on Gmail Addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm actually trying to create a Chat interface in Gmail using Add-ons with App Script. All the interactions are working. But it keeps navigating to different cards rather than have it all in one card. Like in Google Tasks.

Is there a way in which I can just  keep adding sections to the same card dynamically to create a chat like interface.

I assume if it is possible on Google Tasks Add-on it should be possible in this case too. Please help me out as it is a necessary requirement.

Answer (score 1):

**Update :**
Try this

```
    function renderRootCard(){
        var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
        var section = CardService.newCardSection();
        var btnSet = CardService.newButtonSet();
        section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("old widget"));
        section.addWidget(btnSet.addButton(addTaskBtn));
        card.addSection(section);

        var addTask = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("addTask");
        var addTaskBtn = CardService.newTextButton()
            .setText("Add Task")
            .setOnClickAction(addTask); 


        return card.build();
    }

    function addTask(e) {
        var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
        var section = CardService.newCardSection();
        var btnSet = CardService.newButtonSet();
        section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("old widget"));
        section.addWidget(btnSet.addButton(addTaskBtn));
        section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("new widget"));
var addTask = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("addTask");
        var addTaskBtn = CardService.newTextButton()
            .setText("Add Task")
            .setOnClickAction(addTask); 
        return CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(card.build());
    }
```

**Original answer:**

In short: Possible

I understand what you are trying to do. This involves replacing the current card by updating it with a new card that has the same widgets as that of current card and additional widgets that are required.

Let's say, you are building a to-do app. When you click add task(say), you just create the same card, add some widgets and replace the current card with a new one.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I'm trying to achieve. But I haven't come across a code sample or a skeleton. Is it possible for you to share a sample?

Comment: I've added based on your request.

Comment: Doesn't this code work also without the updateCard method? Also the main bit for me is how do I store or pass content of an existing card.

Comment: Akhil, the code has updateCard method . Moreover, I could not find any straight forward way to do this, rather than redrawing the old card again, while doing an update. In order to persist the state of the old card , pass the state of the card to the new card through setParameters method. If CardService allows us the pass the Card as a parameter, we would not have to do this.

Comment: If I have to redraw the whole conversation then first I need to store them separately and recreate the card each time. setParameters doesn't work as well. Have tried that too.

Comment: what parameters did you pass to setParameters ?

Comment: To my stupidity, I was trying to pass a card through it. But obviously that won't work. As I need to store the previous content of the card.

Comment: Can we update the card without rewriting the old code?

Answer (score 0):

I made corrections to the code above and now this works.
The `addTask` and `addTaskBtndefinitions` for the actions needed to go before the creation of the sections and the card itself.

You also need to build the `card.addSection(section);` in the `addTask()` function.

```js
function renderRootCard(){
        var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
        var section = CardService.newCardSection();
        var btnSet = CardService.newButtonSet();
        var addTask = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("addTask");
        var addTaskBtn = CardService.newTextButton()
            .setText("Add Task")
            .setOnClickAction(addTask); 
        section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("old widget"));
        section.addWidget(btnSet.addButton(addTaskBtn));
        card.addSection(section);

        return card.build();
    }

    function addTask(e) {
        var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
        var section = CardService.newCardSection();
        var btnSet = CardService.newButtonSet();
        var addTask = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("addTask");
        var addTaskBtn = CardService.newTextButton()
            .setText("Add Task")
            .setOnClickAction(addTask); 
        section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("old widget"));
        section.addWidget(btnSet.addButton(addTaskBtn));
        section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("new widget"));
        card.addSection(section);

        return CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(card.build());
    }
```

Comment: Can we update the card without rewriting the old code?