# Google Calendar add-on: how to implement a "select all" checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm a new programmer and working on a Google Calendar add-on whose UI is written using CardService. Here's code of its checkbox widget.

```
var calendar = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
  .setFieldName("calendar")
  .addItem("select all", "all", false)
  .addItem("calendar1", "cal1", false)
  .addItem("calendar2", "cal2", false)
```

When I check the "select all" checkbox, I want all checkboxes are checked, while when I uncheck it, any others is also be unchecked. How can I make it?

Furthermore, can I make Google calendar add-on UI with html? Because it seems easier to do so in html. As far as I concerned, workspace add-ons can neither use HTML nor HTMLService to build UI, but [this exsample](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample) uses HTMLServiece in its Settings.gs file in doGet function. That confused me, did I miss something or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Class Selection input doesn't have any methods for setting value except for addItem().

Comment: I think they wanted to keep every this simple so that it would be easy to figure out even for new or non programmers.  Also my guess is they wanted to  make sure that we could mess with their user interface so they jailed addons into a simple language.  Fortunately, you do still have access to apps script for storing and retrieving data.

Comment: @Cooper Though I'm not 100% sure yet, it seems like that editor add-ons can use HTML    and CSS to build their UI but workspace add-ons can't. If they want to keep it simple, why bother differing them?

Comment: Well you may not believe it but many people find HTMLCSS and JavaScript very difficult. Google has embarked on several alternative ways recently app maker was one attempt and now add-ons is perhaps another I find them fairly easy to use and if I need more information from spreadsheets I can always call apps script functions but I have found that add-ons seem to have a quota that limits the maximum time but I haven’t found any data on it so I could be wrong at any rate The car service is what you have and that’s what you have to use.

Comment: Exactly. And about the quota, maybe you would like to read  [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: I didn't see anything in there about addons.

Comment: Well, aren't those quotas and limitations for services and APIs? Maybe you used some of   them? Anyway, thank you for sharing your opinion and good luck with figuring out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using setOnChangeAction() and CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(). In a similar way like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257853/how-can-i-add-new-sections-to-an-existing-card-on-gmail-addon).

And it turns out that Google Workspace add-ons cannot use HTML or CSS.
[Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/gsuite-restrictions)